# Macbook Pro 2012 deleted files become the "other" space and need to know how to delete

Tags: macos, recycle-bin

I have a Macbook Pro mid-2012 15-inch with Catalina 10.15.5. I was continually getting messages that my system hard drive was full. I went to the Manage space, and started deleting large files from downloads, etc. I realized that as they were deleting, the space in other was getting larger with every additional thing I deleted. The trash is empty, but there is still no space on my computer (like 8mb). Not sure what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe asking in https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks...wasn't sure where to ask. Should I delete this post, here?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a quick idea of what folders look like from Terminal

```
du -h -d 1 / 2>/dev/null
```

If you get something like `216G   /Users` you can change that to

```
du -h -d 1 /Users 2>/dev/null
```

And so on. It could also be the system leaving open file handlers, you can check if you have a ton with

```
lsof | grep deleted
```

Or you can try *rebooting* and see if it fixes your issue.